# Snapshot failed, all data cannot be restored

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot

I have 3 nodes, lets say node1, node1, and node3

i have succesfully restored the data from my nodes,
but the data decrease fro, 380k data to 77k data.

```
this is what i get from backup data
"hits": {
"total": 76908,
"max_score": 1,
```

and this is my data

```
"hits": {
"total": 384959,
"max_score": 1,
```

how can i get all my data?

i want to migrate my ES Data to another VM / IP / Instances

Comment: Are you saying you took a snapshot of your data and it is successful but when you restore it you don't see compete data ?

Comment: yap yap, thats right. thats the problem that i cant solve until now @ben5556

Comment: Hi, can you send me your email address ? Its easier to solve it quickly if we can get on a screen share.

Comment: im sorry, i droped the case, and i have another problem on my timeline. but thankyou for trying to help me.

Answer (score 2):

For this, firstly you have to create the index with same mapping, then You can use Reindex API to copy your data to the new index.

Here is, How you can do the same:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "sourceIndex"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "destIndex"
  }
}
```

You can take the reference from the below Link:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-reindex.html

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: the documents still decrease :(